# logstash vs spring cloud data flow, which one is suitable for data preprocessing?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using spring boot along with elasticsearch to make a search system on my website.

I've some data that i need to push in elastic search, this data ( a product for example )  must be processed before ( passed to another micro-service that filters the JSON, adds some fields for a better search result do some calculations and return the object i want to store ). is it possible to do so with log stash, or do i need to use Spring Cloud Data Flow ? thanks in advance.

what i want to do:

```java
save a product ( product service ) 
log the saved product or stream it.
process it before storage ( another service ) 
save the document ( elastic search server )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it depends on various factors but I can try to provide some insights on Spring Cloud Data Flow from the technical standpoint.

If you want to construct a streaming pipeline where your filtering apps are connected via a messaging system that does this flow of data processing, you can checkout Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Spring Cloud Data Flow (and the underlying framework supports such as Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Task) provides the operational benefits over how you manage your streaming pipelines but it may not make sense if you don't need a data pipeline with a messaging system etc., In those cases, you would just stick to a simple Spring Boot app that does this whole filtering model. As soon as you start exploring the distribution of these applications loosely coupled via messaging system, Spring Cloud Data Flow would be handy.

Please checkout SCDF [guide](https://dataflow.spring.io) to understand some of the [features](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/feature-guides/) and [recipes](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/) to know more about what SCDF can offer and choose what fits in your case.